# jQuery and chaining

Tags: jquery, chaining

Sometimes I need to use .off() before .on().

My Question is can I chain them both together or should they remain separate?

Can this:

```
   $('button').off('click');
    $('button;).on('click, function() {
    // code here.
    });
```

Become this and work the same:

```
$('button').off('click').on('click', function() {
 // code here
});
```

Will the .off() execute before the .on() in the chain.

I'm fairly new to chaining this is why I ask.

Comment: jQuery is built so that the vast majority of methods can be chained. Try it and you'll see it works. It would be MUCH quicker than asking on here :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will execute before the `.on()` method.
Basically chaining allows you to write less amount of code and, btw, it fasters it a bit, cause you don't have to find your element multiple times in the DOM tree.(Each time you call `$('#yourElmId')` you basically call `document.getElementById` so if you call it twice - you will perform search of it two times and for big projects it's not great at all)

More details on jquery chaining [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Sorry, was thinking 'bout other stuff at that moment)) Fixed dat.